# What is the explicit birational isomorphism of $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $Z(y^2-x^3-x^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I know that $\mathbb{A}_k^1$ is birationally isomorphic to $Z(y^2-x^3-x^2)$. Apparently the map is given by taking the slope of a line through the origin and mapping it to the other intersection. Geometrically, I can kind of see this since $y^2=x^3+x^2$ is a loop that passes through the origin.

I'm having difficulty making sense of this though. Is there a more algebraic way to do this, perhaps an explicit birational isomorphism?

Comment: That's correct - looking at the slope does it. This is an instance of [blowing-up the singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of slope $s$ is parameterized by $(t, st)$. So set $x = t, y = st$ in the defining equation. This gives

$$s^2 t^2 = t^3 + t^2$$

hence either $t = 0$ or

$$s^2 = t + 1.$$

So the birational map sends $s$ to the point $(s^2 - 1, s(s^2 - 1))$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Qiaochu.